# three.js OBJLoader not loading in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, objloader

I am trying to load an object (.obj) file to use with three.js and react (with react-three-renderer), yet get an 
My code looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React3 from 'react-three-renderer';
import TrackballControls from './TrackballControls';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
OBJLoader(THREE);

class MyClass extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
    ...
    const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
  }
}
```

However, I keep on getting: "export 'OBJLoader' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'
Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So it seems that adding `this.THREE = THREE` to the react component does the trick (weird, eh?).
So my code currently looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React3 from 'react-three-renderer';
import TrackballControls from './TrackballControls';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
OBJLoader(THREE);

class MyClass extends React.Component {
...
  render() {
    ...
    this.THREE = THREE;
    const objLoader = new this.THREE.OBJLoader();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OBJLoader is now part of the core three.js library, so you can access it simply by doing:

```
 const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
```

While removing the lines:

```
import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
OBJLoader(THREE);
```

Since you have already imported the three.js library in your code.

Comment: Am I missing something here? It looks like that exact line of code appears in the OPs code already. Have you changed something to address the problem? If so please explain.

Comment: It is the same line of code, but the 'OBJLoader' function in the original question is appended to the 'THREE' Object by the code 'OBJLoader(THREE);'. This is using an older library/non-standard method, as mentioned in my post, which may be introducing bugs.

Comment: Ah that edit makes your answer much clearer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2019 use **"three-obj-mtl-loader"** instead of `'three-obj-loader'`

```
  import { MTLLoader, OBJLoader } from "three-obj-mtl-loader";
```

Use this method to load material and OBJ model

```
   /**
   * Load and Display OBJ Model
   */
  loadObjModel = (materialURL, objectURL) => {
    new MTLLoader().load(materialURL, materials => {
      materials.preload();
      //materials.Material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
      console.log("Loaded Materials");
      var objLoader = new OBJLoader();
      objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
      objLoader.load(
        objectURL,
        object => {
          //const root = object.detail.loaderRootNode;
          console.log("Loaded Obj" + object);
          let mesh = object;
          this.scene.add(object);
          mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
          mesh.scale.set(0.07, 0.07, 0.07);
        },
        xhr => {
          console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
        },
        // called when loading has errors
        error => {
          console.log("An error happened" + error);
        }
      );
    });
  };
```

Load obj models with material like this

> this.loadObjModel("./assets/windmill-fixed.mtl",
>   "./assets/windmill.obj");