# OBJLoader with React, THREE, Parcel and react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

**WARNING** This is not a copy of [three.js OBJLoader not loading in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191676/three-js-objloader-not-loading-in-react). react-three-renderer is deprecated and I use functional components here.

I need to load an `.obj` file but two problems appear. First, it throws `TypeError: instance is undefined` by react-three-fiber. Second, it loads `.obj` as HTML: `Error: THREE.OBJLoader: Unexpected line: "<!DOCTYPE html>"`.

Are these issues related to Parcel, THREE or react-three-fiber?

Here's the code that doesn't work:

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Canvas } from 'react-three-fiber'
import Model from '/Model'
import Controls from '/Controls'
import '/style.css'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Canvas>
        <Model url="demo.obj" />
        <Controls />
      </Canvas>
    </main>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

**Controls.js**

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useThree, useRender, extend } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'

extend({ OrbitControls })

const Controls = props => {
  const { camera } = useThree()
    const controls = useRef()

    useRender(({ camera }) => {
        controls.current && controls.current.update()
        camera.updateMatrixWorld()
    })
  return <orbitControls ref={controls} args={[camera]} {...props} />
}

export default Controls
```

**Model.js**

```js
import React, { useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import { Math as THREEMath } from 'three'
import { useRender } from 'react-three-fiber'
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'

const Model = ({ url }) => {
    const model = useRef()
  let rot = 0

  const obj = useMemo(() => new OBJLoader().load(url), [url])

    useRender(() => {
        const rad = 5 * Math.sin(THREEMath.degToRad(rot += 0.3))
        model.current.rotation.set(rad, rad, 0)
  })
    return <primitive object={obj} ref={model} />
}

export default Model
```

[OBJ File here](https://gist.github.com/talentlessguy/948f2837693165ff65ab348bb78bc5ef)

Comment: Are you sure you prefixed it with an s3 url for example? I forgot to load it from s3. Or maybe load it from your public folder instead of something locally

Comment: if (!obj) {
return null
}

Answer (score 1):

wrong path. the doctype stuff is the 404 page it pulls. as of r3f 3 you can use the useLoader hook, it makes error handling easier since it's based on react suspense, so you could wrap it into error boundaries and fallbacks.